# Robo_feed rotina da verificação loop if dando pau em python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lógica

Robo_Feed
Sou novo no python, tava querendo desenvolver um robo que pegasse a ultima postagem de alguns portais de noticias aqui da minha região, Com uma pesquisa cheguei a conclusão que seria mais fácil fazer com o modulo feedparser do python.
Então vou tentar explicar o código...

1. Fiz uma class que cuidasse das entradas de dados, nome do site e url, assim fazendo uma lista dos mesmos
2. Defini uma rotina em feed_parser() que extrai os dados das variáveis dando um print pra min na tela das ultimas postagens
3. Coloquei um while dentro do try para chamar as funções
   O script roda lisinho nos 2 primeiros loops depois da pau

**Como disse sou novo e sem experiência, mais com muita vontade de aprender
a programar direito em Python**

**codigo**

```
import feedparser
import time
import base64
timeaut = 15

class Robo_Feed(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.sites= {}
        self.allheadlines = []
    def append_url(self, name, site):
        self.sites[name] = (site)
    def encrip(self, published):
        self.data.append(base64.b64encode(published))

def feed_parser():
    def parseRSS(rss_url):
        return feedparser.parse(rss_url)
    def getHeadlines(rss_url):
        robo.headlines = []
        feed = parseRSS(rss_url)
        if (base64.b64encode(feed.entries[0].published)) in str(robo.data):
            return robo.headlines
        else:
            POSTAGEN = '*'+feed['feed']['title']+'*' +"\n" + feed.entries[0].title + "\n" + feed.entries[0].link + "\n\r"
            print (POSTAGEN)
            robo.encrip(feed.entries[0].published)
            return robo.headlines
    for key, url in robo.sites.items():
        robo.allheadlines.extend(getHeadlines(url))

robo = Robo_Feed()
robo.append_url('Oglobo', 'http://oglobo.globo.com/rss.xml?secao=ece_frontpage')
robo.append_url('ZeroHora', 'http://zh.clicrbs.com.br/rs/ultimas-noticias-rss/')

try:
    while True:
        feed_parser()
        time.sleep(time)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Umteromped"
```

**Erro**

```
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/BotTelegran/testes.py", line 38, in <module>
    feed_parser()
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/BotTelegran/testes.py", line 30, in feed_parser
    robo.allheadlines.extend(getHeadlines(url))
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/BotTelegran/testes.py", line 22, in getHeadlines
    if (base64.b64encode(feed.entries[0].published)) in str(robo.data):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer o código rodar, o problema que estava acontecendo era na codificação para base 64, que só funciona para caracteres ASCII, bastou converter para ASCII antes de converter.

Outro problema foi no `time.sleep(timeaut)` que estava chamando o modulo `time` ao invés da variável com o tempo de espera  .

Segue o código funcionando.

```
import feedparser
import time
import base64
timeaut = 15

class Robo_Feed(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.sites= {}
        self.allheadlines = []

    def append_url(self, name, site):
        self.sites[name] = (site)

    def encrip(self, published):
        self.data.append(base64.standard_b64encode(published.encode('ascii')))

def feed_parser():
    def parseRSS(rss_url):
        return feedparser.parse(rss_url)

    def getHeadlines(rss_url):
        robo.headlines = []
        feed = parseRSS(rss_url)

        if (base64.standard_b64encode(feed.entries[0].published.encode('ascii')) in robo.data):
            return robo.headlines
        else:
            POSTAGEN = '*'+feed['feed']['title']+'*' +"\n" + feed.entries[0].title + "\n" + feed.entries[0].link + "\n\r"
            print (POSTAGEN)
            robo.encrip(feed.entries[0].published)
            return robo.headlines

    for key, url in robo.sites.items():
        robo.allheadlines.extend(getHeadlines(url))

robo = Robo_Feed()
robo.append_url('Oglobo', 'http://oglobo.globo.com/rss.xml?secao=ece_frontpage')
robo.append_url('ZeroHora', 'http://zh.clicrbs.com.br/rs/ultimas-noticias-rss/')

try:
    while True:
        feed_parser()
        time.sleep(timeaut)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Umteromped")
```